# How can I receive two request in one jsp from other jsp files?

Tags: javascript, java, html

there are three files.

fileUpload.html, upload.jsp, SQLProcess.jsp

fileUpload.html include html tag to send file information to upload.jsp by using 'post' method.

the file from fileUpload.html is csv. 
in upload.jsp, read csv file and then parse the data, save them into database. if there are errors, it shows them with html table. and also there is a form. the user can correct this error data by filling out the form. if they click the send button, the form they completed send to SQLProcess.jsp (post method).

In SQLProcess.jsp, parse the form data from upload.jsp. and save them into database. and I want to return whether this commit is success or not.

but I can't return this result (success or not) to upload .jsp

How can I do this?

I want to send the result whether the sql execution is success or not (true or false) to upload.jsp

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't return this result"? Which way did you try? What happened? Probably some example code could help everyone to understand what you're trying to do!

Comment: I want to send the result whether the sql execution is success or not (true or false) to upload.jsp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only method of transport between the JSP files is the web browser. 
So, if your process looks like this:

```
fileUpload.html ==POST==> upload.jsp ==POST==> SQLProcess.jsp
```

then `SQLProcess.jsp` should redirect the webbrowser back to `upload.jsp` using a `302` redirect. Probably something like

```
String status = getStatus();
response.sendRedirect( 'upload.jsp?status='+status );
```

Of course you can also just display the message from `SQLProcess.jsp` directly.